Covering finite sets with a set of least measure?
What is the least measure of a set $X\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ such that for any finite set $Y\subseteq \mathbb{R}$, there always exists a real number, $t$ such that $Y\subseteq X+t$?
Context: I am a 2nd year undergrad student who has studied metric analysis. I just thought this up as an extension question for this choice of $X$
$X:=\bigcup\left\{ n\in2\mathbb{N} : \left(\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i},\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}\frac{1}{i}\right)\right\}$
I still failed for above. My attempt was to try to capture each point in order in shrinking domains and use choice to change the value of $t$ iteratively to capture each point one at a time.

If you restrict to $Y$ of size (at most) $2$, then you can do with a set of measure zero - let $X={n+c\mid n\in\mathbb Z,c\in C}$ where $C\subseteq[0,1]$ is the Cantor set. I suspect you can find $X$ of measure zero which works for all finite $Y$ but off the top of my head I don't have an example.

If $X$ has this property, then so does $cX$ for any $c>0$, so if the measure is positive and finite, we can change it arbitrarily. Therefore the only real questions here are: is there such a set $X$ of finite measure, and is there such a set of measure 0?

For brevity we call a set $X \subset \mathbb R$ neat if for all finite $F \subset \mathbb R$ there exists $t \in \mathbb R$ such that $F \subset t + X$.
As was pointed out in a comment by Wojowu there are two reasonable questions to ask:

Does there exist a neat set with zero Lebesgue measure?
Does there exist a neat set with finite Lebesgue measure?

In this answer I construct a neat set with finite Lebesgue measure, thus positively answering the second question. Despite not answering the first question I decided to write this as an answer, since the construction seems to be too long for a comment.
At first we make the following
Observation. A set $X \subset \mathbb R^n$ is neat iff for all finite collections $t_1, \dots, t_n \in \mathbb R$ the set $\bigcap_{k = 1}^n (t_k + X)$ is not empty.
The proof is clear since $$\exists t: \{t_1, \dots, t_k\} \subset t + X \Leftrightarrow \exists t: -t \in -t_j + X,\; j = 1, \dots, n \Leftrightarrow \bigcap_{k = 1}^n (-t_k + X) \ne \emptyset.$$
Corollary. Every open dense subset $X \subset \mathbb R$ is neat.
This is clear from the fact that the intersection of a finite number of open dense subsets (in arbitrary topological space) is again open and dense.
Now we construct an open dense subset in $\mathbb R$ with finite Lebesgue measure. In order to do this we outline a generalization of the Cantor set $C \subset [0,1]$ that has dense complement in [0,1], but unlike classical Cantor set it has non-zero measure that can be chosen arbitrarily in (0,1). These sets are usually called fat Cantor sets. One of the constructions goes as follows. Fix $\alpha \in (0,1/3)$. Start by removing the (open) middle part of $[0,1]$ with length $\alpha$. After that remove the middle parts of two remaining intervals with lengths $\alpha^2$ and proceed by induction. We denote the resulting Cantor set by $C_\alpha$. It is clear that $[0,1] \setminus C_\alpha$ has measure $$m_\alpha = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty 2^{n-1} \alpha^{n} = \alpha / (1 - 2\alpha).$$
Clearly by choosing $\alpha$ close to $0$ we achieve that the measure of $[0,1]\setminus C_\alpha$ approaches $0$. Finally, $C_\alpha$ is nowhere dense by the exactly same reasons that worked for classical Cantor set.
Finally, for each $n \in \mathbb Z$ choose $\alpha_n \in (0, 1/3)$ such that $\sum_{n \in \mathbb Z} m_{\alpha_n} < \infty$. Let
$$X = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb Z} (n + [0, 1] \setminus C_{\alpha_n}).$$
It is easy to see that this set is open, dense, and has finite Lebesgue measure. In fact, by choosing the parameters $\alpha_n$ wisely, we could achieve arbitrarily small set (in the sense of Lebesgue measure), which agrees with the Wojowu's comment.
EDIT: for completeness I add here an answer to the first question, that was given by Wojowu in the comments.
Proposition. If $X$ is a countable intersection of open dense sets, then it is neat.
Indeed, the set $\bigcap_{k = 1}^n (t_k + X)$ is again a countable intersection of open dense sets and is not empty by Baire theorem.
Now if $X_n$ is an open dense set with measure $m_n \rightarrow 0$, then $\bigcap_n X_n$ is a neat set with measure $0$.

Another way to produce an open dense subset of arbitrarily small measure is to enumerate the rationals in some fashion, and then union together open balls of radius $\epsilon/2^n$ around each rational $q_n$ in the ordering.

Can you elaborate or point to a reference on why the intersection of two open dense sets must be dense? It's not immediately obvious to me.

@RavenclawPrefect I could be wrong but isn't that just the real line?

@yolo It is not. Most direct way to see that is that this union has measure at most $\epsilon$ by subadditivity, so it cannot be a whole line. Explicitly giving an element not in this union will be tricky since it depends on the enumeration.

@RavenclawPrefect Let $U,V$ be open dense, $x\in\mathbb R$. Any neighbourhood $N$ of $x$ intersects $U$, and then $N\cap U$ is nonempty open so also intersects $V$, hence $N$ intersects $U\cap V$.

Combining this with Baire category theorem gives a measure zero set: for each $n\in\mathbb N$ let $X_n$ be an open dense set of measure $\leq 1/n$ (using either your or RavenclawPrefect's classical construction). $X=\bigcap)n X_n$ has measure zero and I claim it is neat. Indeed for any $t_1,\dots,t_k$, we have $\bigcap_i X+t_i=\bigcap_i\bigcap_n X_n+t_i$ is a countable intersection of open dense subsets, which by Baire is nonempty.
